# Problem with url in plugin's templates in Cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I'm creating a plugin in Cakephp 4 for CRUD email alias through my webhosting's API (OVH API).

My plugin `OvhManager` uses prefix `Admin` and contains :

- `EmailAliasController`
- templates `index`, `add`, `edit`

The layout used to render this templates is the App's one (named `admin-layout` and outside of my plugin).

When I follow a route of my plugin (e.g `/admin/ovh-manager/email-alias/index`), all the links in the layout are wrong because they all have `'plugin' => 'OvhManager'` automatically added.

I could add `'plugin' => null` to all the links of the layout but it seems a hard work to me.

Is there a better way to disable plugin in the links generated in the layout ?

For example is there a way in my `EMailAliasController::beforeFilter()` to tell to use `admin-layout` but without adding the plugin OvhManager to the routes ?

Comment: `'plugin' => null` is the correct solution.

Comment: @GregSchmidt You mean there is no other way ? Because I find it weird to have to build links in an app layout always having in mind to add `'plugin' => null` just in case the layout would be rendered with a plugin template. Can't it be done by default ?

Comment: If there is no `plugin` argument given to the link function, it defaults to whatever plugin is currently executing. I suppose you could make your own HTML helper that extends the default one and changes this specific bit of functionality.